# Spelling errors hidden while highlighting line in vim

Tags: vim

When there's a misspelling (with `set spell`), it highlights it red (good!), but when the line is highlighted as my current line the red goes away (bad). Removing `set cul` fixes the problem, but *how do I keep the word marked red while being highlighted*? I may have multiple words misspelled on a line and also while typing the misspellings are hidden until I go to the next which kinda sucks.

vimrc: https://gist.github.com/OscarGodson/d1b05d52df4ff160b891
colorscheme: https://github.com/tomasr/molokai

Comment: What colourscheme are you using?

Comment: @PrinceGoulash duh I forgot to share those. I updated my answer to include my vimrc and color scheme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) one could change the vim color scheme, or the SpellBad highlight scheme; one example of the second case is to add in vimrc the following,

```
hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad cterm=bold
```

2) (not a solution) someone might find 'spell checking while composing' is a bit annoying / distracting and prefer switching the spell checking off until they finish writing the article.

Comment: `hi SpellBad cterm=underline` more recognizable and eye catchy, in `insert` mode  underscore looks exactly like in gui word processor. (For every taste: bold / italic / underline )

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the cursorline highlighting has priority over the syntax highlighting (spell errors belong to that), and that cannot be changed. (You can only specify the priority with the newer `matchadd()` functions.)

I've once [raised this issue for error highlighting](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/46c70a229488de20), but nothing came out of it. (I'd still like to implement a patch for that one day.)

The problem is only about overlap of background highlighting; in GVIM, most color schemes use the *undercurl* attribute to avoid that issue. In the console, you can only change the highlighting to foreground color, italic or bold attributes to work around it.

#### workaround

One clever workaround involves swapping the foreground and background colors while adding the `reverse` attribute: Turn

```
hi SpellBad cterm=NONE ctermbg=red ctermfg=white
```

to

```
hi SpellBad cterm=reverse ctermbg=white ctermfg=red
```

These two changes cancel each other out normally, but on a CursorLine, the foreground color now contributes to the coloring, turning hard-to-read white-on-cursorline to red-on-cursorline.

Comment: Simple trick: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/cursorline-colors

Answer (score 0):

Curiously, and jumping off of both answers from the other posters, adding the following in my vimrc made my red background persist accidentally due to my terminal not being able to fulfill the "italic" switch because it can't mix font types like that (I think). I stuck it in the section of my vimrc that is tested for gvim because gvim underlines my spelling mistakes without issue. Give it a try!

```
if has("gui_running")
    #all my gvim settings
else #we're in terminal
    hi clear SpellBad
    hi SpellBad cterm=bold,italic ctermfg=red
endif
```